# Have GA4 run a report that shows both landing page and search term?

Tags: google-analytics, reporting, google-analytics-4

I was wondering if it was possible to have a report in GA4 showing the landing page a user came in on and the organic search query. Currently, I can see a report with the landing pages on and I can see a separate report under the search console for the queries but I would like to combine them so I can see both the search query and the landing page.

The 2 reports I want to combine:
Engagement > Landing Page
Search Console >  Queries

I have done some googling on this matter but I can't seem to find an answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

[image]

If I add the landing page value to the queries report it shows this, I just don't understand why.

[image]